# this.store.peekAll() and firstObject

Tags: ember.js

Let's assume following code of route:

```
model() {
  return this.store.peekAll('user');
}
```

and simple template:

```
{{ model.firstObject.name }}
```

I would like to push that `firstObject` part into model because I always want to use only first record. With Ember objects it should be possible to use:

```
return this.store.peekAll('user').get('firstObject')
```

but this is not working because peekAll does not return Ember object in such way. What is the correct way of doing this?

[*] I'm using peekAll() instead of peekRecord() because peekRecord does not update when data in store are changed.

Answer (score -1):

can you try:

```
return this.store.peakAll('user').then((users) => {
    return users.get('firstObject');
});
```

Comment: peekAll return RecordArray which extends Ember.ArrayProxy - so it's not thenable - not a promise - firstObject property should work. Make sure you first call store.findAll('user') to fetch records into the store -  maybe in your application route before you try to access this collection by invoking peekAll.

Comment: xoma is right. An attempt to try your code ends with error: TypeError: this.store.peekAll(...).then is not a function

Comment: @xoma I'm using this approach because I don't have data loaded in a moment that page is accessed (it just takes too long, so they are loaded async). ArrayProxy handles this nicely. Currently, my other work-around is to use ember-data-filter together with this.store.filter() as I don't want to do filtering in template.

Comment: Yes, if you need a live array, which store.query does not return, you should use the ember-data-filter addon. My point was that peekAll() will return e-d array where u can access firstObject and see the results - as long as it's not empty.